# REST api PUT request returns status 504 and 204 using Postman

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, put, postman

I am testing a REST API endpoint PUT request using Postman. I get a status 504 ( in Asia), but my other team member gets a status 204 (in America). The API is hosted at AWS.

First, we thought I might be doing something wrong. My team member sent me the .postman_collection file of his request. I imported and ran it, but I'm still getting 504.

Any idea what could the reason be?

(we guessed it could be a region issue, but it shouldn't be. Do you think so? Or could it be something else?)

All POST and GET requests of that API succeed when I test them on Postman, but PUT on all endpoints of that API return 504.

Comment: Please check the AWS IAM permission for the API whether PUT is allowed for this endpoint.

Comment: may be your request is going to different availability zones